# steps for launching 2nd instance of drupalvm

Tags: drupal, virtual-machine

Am I overlooking something in DrupalVM documentation? To run multiple instances, what steps do people follow?

I’ve seen mentions that after you’ve launched DrupalVM once, it’s quick to launch another instance.

Various approaches have had the same results, including some of the helpers on http://docs.drupalvm.com/en/latest/other/management-tools as well as the vagrant plugin vagrant-cachier. With each, starting a new instance takes the same (very long) length of time….

Answer (score 1):

First, do you really need to launch 2 same machines at once? You can have multiple websites (vhosts) on one VM. That way you would save some computer resources (memory). Edit hosts file on your (host) machine to match web server settings, where you defined your website

But if you insist, should be possible to copy whole project dir, change ip of one of those 2 machine (config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.something.something" in vagrant file) and run them simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for your response @MilanG. Scenario is dev environments needing to match webhosts, and different projects having different environment requirements. To date we've been copying the whole project dir as you describe. In doing so, the spin-up time is as long on the nth environment as on the first. In a few places in docs/recorded presentations, it sounds like people have a way to shorten spinup time of subsequent drupalvms --but it's also possible I've misunderstood and there's no "better way" than what we're already doing. Any insights?